# Cannot find the delivered file after scp it from sever to the lcoal

Tags: bash, scp

I'd like to scp a file to the local

```
[root@iz2ze9wve43n2nyuvmsfx5z ~]# scp root@www.**sever.com:/root/crond_help.md .
root@www.*server.com's password: 
crond_help.md                                 100% 7692     1.7MB/s   00:00
```

It seems succeeding to complete the task:

Nonetheless, I cannot find it anywhere on the local

```
me in ~/Desktop/PubRepo
$ find / -iregex ".*crond_help.md" 2>/dev/null
#None returned
```

I tried multiple times, the results stay the same.

What's the problem with my usage of scp?

Comment: The command looks right. The problem is with the directory or the server that you are running the command in.

Comment: i think it must be in your  home folder of root /root since you copied it to the '.' directory when you where in the root home folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already ssh into server `[root@iz2ze9wve43n2nyuvmsfx5z ~]`, is that right?

Please exit and return `me in ~/Desktop/PubRepo`